# Create given string from dictionary entries

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, backtracking

During a recent job interview, I was asked to give a solution to the following problem:

Given a string `s` (without spaces) and a dictionary, return the words in the dictionary that compose the string.

For example, `s= peachpie, dic= {peach, pie}, result={peach, pie}`.

I will ask the the decision variation of this problem:

> if `s` can be composed of words in the
>   dictionary return `yes`, otherwise
>   return `no`.

My solution to this was in backtracking (written in Java)

```
public static boolean words(String s, Set<String> dictionary)
{
    if ("".equals(s))
        return true;

    for (int i=0; i <= s.length(); i++)
    {
        String pre = prefix(s,i); // returns s[0..i-1]
        String suf = suffix(s,i); // returns s[i..s.len]
        if (dictionary.contains(pre) && words(suf, dictionary))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Set<String> dic = new HashSet<String>();
    dic.add("peach");
    dic.add("pie");
    dic.add("1");

    System.out.println(words("peachpie1", dic)); // true
    System.out.println(words("peachpie2", dic)); // false
}
```

What is the time complexity of this solution?
I'm calling recursively in the for loop, but only for the prefix's that are in the dictionary.

Any idea's?

Comment: Does the word need to be composed of words of the dictionary only? For example, what would be the result for *applepie* if *apple* is not in the dictionary?

Comment: @Gumbo Looking at his example the last line contains some, but not all words (the # 2 is missing) so the dictionary must contain all words. Is repitition allowed? For example, "peachpeach" should be true or false given the dictionary in the example?

Comment: @Mackey Repitition wasn't defined, but I'm assuming it is allowed

Comment: @Gumbo, the result of `applepie` is obviously false. Look at the definition of the problem: if s can be composed of words in the dictionary return yes. `apple` isn't in the dictionary

Comment: wouldn't this only work on strings composed of 1 or 2 words though? If it was `"tastyapplepie"` and `{'tasty','apple','pie'}` it wouldn't work.

Comment: @Matt it works because I'm calling `words` recursively on the suffix.

Comment: Are words allowed to overlap?  What is the desired answer if `dictionary = {"abc", "bcd"}` and `word = "abcd"`?

Comment: @j no. the answer to your example is false.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can easily create a case where program takes at least exponential time to complete. Let's just take a word `aaa...aaab`, where `a` is repeated `n` times. Dictionary will contain only two words, `a` and `aa`.

`b` in the end ensure that function never finds a match and thus never exits prematurely.

On each `words` execution, two recursive calls will be spawned: with `suffix(s, 1)` and `suffix(s, 2)`. Execution time, therefore, grows like fibonacci numbers: `t(n) = t(n - 1) + t(n - 2)`. (You can verify it by inserting a counter.) So, complexity is certainly not polynomial. (and this is not even the worst possible input)

But you can easily improve your solution with [Memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization). Notice, that output of function `words` depends on one thing only: at which position in original string we're starting. E.e., if we have a string `abcdefg` and `words(5)` is called, it doesn't matter how exactly `abcde` is composed (as `ab+c+de` or `a+b+c+d+e` or something else). Thus, we don't have to recalculate `words("fg")` each time.
In the primitive version, this can be done like this

```
public static boolean words(String s, Set<String> dictionary) {
    if (processed.contains(s)) {
        // we've already processed string 's' with no luck
        return false;
    }

    // your normal computations
    // ...

    // if no match found, add 's' to the list of checked inputs
    processed.add(s);
    return false;
}
```

PS Still, I do encourage you to change `words(String)` to `words(int)`. This way you'll be able to store results in array and even transform the whole algorithm to DP (which would make it much simpler).

**edit 2**
Since I have not much to do besides work, here's the DP (dynamic programming) solution. Same idea as above.

```
    String s = "peachpie1";
    int n = s.length();
    boolean[] a = new boolean[n + 1];
    // a[i] tells whether s[i..n-1] can be composed from words in the dictionary
    a[n] = true; // always can compose empty string

    for (int start = n - 1; start >= 0; --start) {
        for (String word : dictionary) {
            if (start + word.length() <= n && a[start + word.length()]) {
                // check if 'word' is a prefix of s[start..n-1]
                String test = s.substring(start, start + word.length());
                if (test.equals(word)) {
                    a[start] = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println(a[0]);
```

Comment: Not so easy.. I ran it with n=20, it took 28656 iterations. So this is exponential if x == ~1.67, (1.67^20 == 28656)... which doesn't really seem like the case

Comment: is t(n - 1) + t(n - 2) + t(n-3) + ... not just t(n - 1) + t(n - 2).

Comment: @Saeed In this example, there're only two words in dictionary. Obviously, if you consider the worst possible input, time will be worse.

Comment: Size of the dictionary shouldnt matter. Implementation with a hash set  is O(1), no matter how big the dictionary is

Comment: @Itsik You can't estimate algorithm complexity basing on one measurement: there're always smaller constants. Otherwise, I could always take `n=3` and say complexity is `O(1)` :) Try running it for `n=30` or `35` and see how nicely it grows.

Comment: n=30 ==> 3524577, n=35 ==> 39088168

Comment: @Itsik Size of the dictionary matters for the number of recursive calls made inside a given call. In my example each time 2 calls are spawned, but it can be much more.

Comment: @Itsik Why is `2` important? Perhaps I asked a wrong question in my first comment to you: I should've asked what's wrong with `x = 1.67`. (or any other number) `1.67^n` still grows exponentially. Look, you can't even handle `n = 40` within reasonable time :)

Comment: Well, 2 isn't important. If it is exponential, I would like a combinatoric approach to it, and not by doing math analysis. It also isn't 1.67, because that is only `x` for n=20, it changes for 30,35 ... and n=40 ==> 433494436

Comment: Regarding the implementation, I just sketched this up... it's not really important, it was an interview question

Comment: @Itsik What do you mean by "combinatoric approach"?

Comment: Like your initial approach `t(n) = t(n-1) ..`, but one that is correct :)

Comment: @Itsik As for the actual complexity... First, please note that this is only one possible input I provided: actual (worst case) complexity of your method is worse. Second... AFAIK, you can limit from below the growth of fibonacci sequence by exponential function. But something with more math experience could answer this better. Anyway, my point was that this algorithm is no way polynomial and thus can't really be used in practice.

Comment: n^1000 is still polynomial but not practical (and again, this is a theoretical question)

Comment: @Itsik I still do think complexity in this example is approximated by fibonacci numbers (on each step you call `words` twice: with substring one character shorter and two characters shorter). The problems are 1) Fibonacci numbers function is not exponential itself, but it can be bordered by exponential function from below (easy to show) and 2) finding complexity function for this example doesn't give you complexity of the algorithm: this is far from worst example.

Comment: I like the dynamic programming approach it is much faster. But I was asking the question because I was having trouble analyzing my own algorithm.

Comment: @Itsik In practice, usually, knowing that complexity of your algorithm is bound by exponential function from below is enough :) If you need even worse example, expand dictionary to contain `"aaa", "aaaa", "aaaaa", ...`. This will lead Catalan-numbers growth, as in answer by *Saeed*. But finding **the worst** example and proving that this one is **the worst** is, I'm afraid, impossible.

Comment: @Itsik Maybe if you formalize what you want, somebody could help you.

Comment: @Nikita, I think what I want is pretty clear. What is the worst time complexity of this algorithm? I want a tight upper-bound. Ofcourse I know that this is bound by exponential, or factorial function. If you say it's exponential, atleast tell me what is the base of the exponent and explain the logic behind it. We already figured out, that if this is exponential it's less than 2. And again, the purpose isn't testing if the method is practical, its testing the ability to analyze the solution

Comment: @Itsik When you calculate complexity, base (or any other parameters) doesn't matter. So, when you say complexity is exponential (`O(x^n)`) it may as well be `35*(x^(1.6*n))*(n^7 - 8n) + 9*n^2*logn`. Although calculating `x` here may be fun, it has little practical sense :)

Comment: @Itsik *and explain the logic behind it*  I believe the logic is pretty simple. 1) Number of steps for this example grows like fibonacci sequence -> 2) Fibonacci sequence grows faster than some exponential function -> 3) Execution time for *this example* grows faster than some exponential function `f(n)` -> 4) Execution time for the *worst example* grows faster than some exponential function `f(n)`. Note, this doesn't prove worst time is exponential: it can be as well factorial or worse. (I have no idea how Catalan numbers grow)

Comment: BTW, both 28656+1, 3524577+1 and 39088168+1 are fibonacci numbers :) http://planetmath.org/encyclopedia/ListOfFibonacciNumbers.html

Comment: @Nikita Rybak, if you think the dictionary size is 2, I think you are wrong, or the `OP` doing very bad work (I just answered your first comment for me, I didn't read the other comments)

Comment: @Saeed Instead of reading the first comment, you could've read the post. I said very clearly that this is complexity *for this particular input*. I also clearly stated that there're worse inputs, but even for this one complexity is already exponential.

Comment: @Itsik: From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Relation_to_the_golden_ratio, the nth Fibonacci number is `(z^n - (-1/z)^n)/sqrt(5)`, where `z` is the golden ratio (1.618...)  That is clearly bounded from below by `(z^n - 1)/sqrt(5)`, since the 2nd term in the numerator is a number with absolute value < 1 that will become smaller (alternating around 0) as `n` increases.  Thus your algorithm has `O(z^n)` (exponential-time) performance on this input -- and as Nikita says, it will be even worse on worse inputs.

Comment: I accepted the answer, after convincing myself. I took your example, but added all the prefixes to the dictionary, and got worst case 2^n iterations when the answer is false. Although, I would like to add, that when the answer is true, my algorithm is 2x faster. (Try it yourself)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a dynamic programming solution that counts the total number of ways to decompose the string into words. It solves your original problem, since the string is decomposable if the number of decompositions is positive.

```
def count_decompositions(dictionary, word):
    n = len(word)
    results = [1] + [0] * n
    for i in xrange(1, n + 1):
        for j in xrange(i):
            if word[n - i:n - j] in dictionary:
                results[i] += results[j]
    return results[n]
```

Storage O(n), and running time O(n^2).

Comment: As I wrote to Nikita, I like the dynamic programming approach, it is much faster. But I was asking the question because I was having trouble analyzing my own algorithm.

Comment: @Paul:  Could you explain how this algorithm works, or at least what the content of "results" means?  I'm having a hard time following what this is supposed to achieve, and how it counts the number of decompositions.

Comment: @divegeek: I'll take a stab.  `results[i]` is the number of ways of decomposing the last `i` characters of the string using dictionary words.  We work backwards from the end of the string towards the front, always making use of decomposition counts for suffixes we've already computed.  It would be slightly easier to understand if `results[i]` just stored 1 for "at least 1 decomposition of the last i characters is possible" and 0 otherwise, in which case the innermost `if` would be written `if word[n-i:n-j] in dictionary and results[j] == 1 then results[i] = 1` in effect.

Comment: @divegeek: In the simplified algorithm I proposed, the outer loop goes through each suffix in increasing length order.  The inner (`j`) loop is essentially asking: "Is there any shorter decomposable suffix of `j` characters that can be used to get a decomposable suffix of `i` characters?"  (Remember `j < i`.)  The fact that it's possible to compute not just whether this is possible but in fact the number of distinct decompositions is just some fancy showing off :)

Comment: @j_random_hacker: Your simpler version can be done by changing `+=` to `|=` in the code.

Comment: @Paul: Sure :)  But I find I understand things like this more easily by taking it a step at a time.  :)

Comment: Thanks, guys.  I spent some time thinking about it and I get it now, and even the thought process behind it.  Very slick.  I didn't find that j_random_hacker's revision made it simpler -- nor more difficult.  Same process, just a different way of collecting the results.

Answer (score 0):

The loop on all the string will take `n`. Finding all suffixes and prefixes will take `n + (n - 1) + (n - 2) + .... + 1` (`n` for first call of `words`, `(n - 1)` for second and so on), which is

```
n^2 - SUM(1..n) = n^2 - (n^2 + n)/2 = n^2 / 2 - n / 2
```

which in complexity theory is equivalent to n^2.

Checking for existence in HashSet in normal case is Theta(1), but in worst case it is O(n).

So, normal case complexity of your algorithm is Theta(n^2), and worst case - O(n^3).

**EDIT:** I confused order of recursion and iteration, so this answer is wrong. Actually time depends on `n` exponentially (compare with computation of Fibonacci numbers, for example).

More interesting thing is the question how to improve your algorithm. Traditionally for string operations **[suffix tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree)** is used. You can build suffix tree with your string and mark all the nodes as "untracked" at the start of the algo. Then go through the strings in a set and each time some node is used, mark it as "tracked". If all strings in the set are found in the tree, it will mean, that the original string *contains* all the substrings from set. And if all the nodes are marked as tracked, it will mean, that string consists *only* of substring from set.

Actual complexity of this approach depends on many factors like tree building algorithm, but at least it allows to divide the problem into several independent subtasks and so measure final complexity by complexity of the most expensive subtask.

Comment: It's pretty good `O(n^3)`: you have to wait a minute an answer for `n = 40` :)